# Change Video Volume via jquery

Tags: jquery, video, volume

I want to change the volume of a video using jQuery. So far it's not working. The `trigger('play')` works. Is it a problem because the element has no id?

```
jQuery('.v1 .wpb_single_image').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).addClass(".v1 open-video"); //add the class to the clicked element
  jQuery(".v1 video").trigger('play');
  jQuery(".v1 video").volume = 1.0;
});
```

If but by nice if somebody can help me out.

Comment: Note that the arguments you provide to the `addClass()` method don't need the `.` prefix on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`volume` is a property of the `video` Element, not of a jQuery object. Therefore you need to use the `prop()` method:

```js
$(".v1 video").prop('volume', 1.0);
```

Alternatively you can access the video Element directly:

```js
$(".v1 video").get(0).volume = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full function for changing the video volume using jQuery

```
//! with jQuery update video volume
$(function () {
  // getting the video and custom input slider using jQuery
  const video = $("#my_video");
  const volumeslider = $("#volumeslider");

   // logging in the console to verify if the elements exists
   console.log("jquery video element", video);
   console.log("volumeslider element", volumeslider);


   $(document).on("input change", "#volumeslider", function () {
  // getting the volume on slide
  const volume = $(this).val();
  console.log("volume value", volume);

  $("#my_video").prop("volume", Number(volume) / 100);

 });
});
```

Here is the html for the video and input slider

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop id="my_video">
    <source src="https://matchplicity.com/wp- 
        content/uploads/2023/05/matchplicity-online-video- 
        cutter.com_.mp4"
        type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://matchplicity.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/matchplicity-online-video-cutter.com_.mp4"
        type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
```